# Ruby 3DES implementation vs PHP mcrypt, different results

Tags: php, ruby, 3des

I'm trying to migrate some legacy PHP code to ruby, and I've encountered a problem with some 3DES encryption. This is the PHP implementation using mcrypt:

```
function encrypt_3DES($message, $key){

    $bytes = array(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0); //byte [] IV = {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}
    $iv = implode(array_map("chr", $bytes)); //PHP 4 >= 4.0.2

    $ciphertext = mcrypt_encrypt(MCRYPT_3DES, $key, $message, MCRYPT_MODE_CBC, $iv); 
    return $ciphertext;
}
```

and this is my ruby code:

```
def encrypt_3DES(message, key)
  des=OpenSSL::Cipher.new('des3')
  des.encrypt
  des.key = key
  des.update(message)+des.final
end
```

However results are slightly different (base64 encoded):

```
//PHP
ZpgH7NWpRx+Mi6tDBZ9q2Q==

# Ruby
ZpgH7NWpRx/usGDIsQ+A8A==
```

As you can see it's the lowest portion of the string's bytes that differs. Any pointers are much appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I answer my own question.

It was an issue about how openssl and mcrypt implementations use padding. My cryptography knowledge isn't too deep, but I found a usable code sample here http://opensourcetester.co.uk/2012/11/29/zeros-padding-3des-ruby-openssl/

```
#ENCRYPTION
block_length = 8
des.padding = 0 #Tell Openssl not to pad
des.encrypt
json = '{"somekey":"somevalue"}'
json += "\0" until json.bytesize % block_length == 0 #Pad with zeros
edata = des.update(json) + des.final 
b64data = Base64.encode64(edata).gsub("\n",'')
```

Basically, ruby openssl will use PKCS padding, while mcrypt uses 0 padding. So in our code I had to tell openssl not to pad the string with `des.padding = 0` and then do the padding manually: `json += "\0" until json.bytesize % block_length == 0`.

Those are the important bits that were missing in my original implementation.

Answer (score 0):

Could the `PHP` combination of `MCRYPT_3DES` and `MCRYPT_MODE_CBC` not be equivalent to the ruby `OpenSSL` library's `3des` (or `des-ede3-cbc`). [There are examples of other mismatches](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19718060/des3-encryption-ruby-opensslcipher-vs-oracle-dbms-obfuscation-toolkit).

Try one of the other modes, such as `des-ede-cbc` or `des-cbc` (See full list [here](http://www.openssl.org/docs/manmaster/apps/enc.html))

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but in the end it turned to be a different issue about how ruby openssl and php mcrypt use padding for block ciphers (see my answer)

Comment: @sjaime your solution is interesting. I can see that being worth knowing about in the future.